# SVN: 'Checkout As' operation finished with error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I am using eclipse kepler SR2, I would like to get a maven project from svn server, for that I installed **subversion** ( I tried to install subclipse but I got this error

> Operation details
>   Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201303011221)
>   Missing requirement: Maven SCM Handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221) requires 'bundle org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core [1.6.0,1.9.0)' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201303011221)
>   To: org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse [0.13.0.201303011221]

)

When I do : new -> other -> maven -> Check out Maven Projects from SCM and I choose the svn project url then I click  next and finish I got this error :

> SVN: 'Checkout As' operation finished with error
>   Selected resource is not checked out.
>   Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
>   If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
>   If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.

Any I idea to solve this problem or a way to install subclipse, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Subversive - SVN Team Provider plugin. It gives you SVN views (svn repositories etc.) just like git repositories.

1. add your svn repository;
2. checkout the repository;
3. import maven project (pass the root directory of your project)